# Criminal- traveling history

Tags: usa, us-residents, criminal-records, honduran-citizens

I had two felonies on my record for 2017.

Burglary of an unoccupied structure (unarmed) and
Damage of property ($1,000 or more).

I pleaded guilty to both.

Both were actually DISMISSED through the diversion program, where if completed, charges are DROPPED and not put on your record. Although I can still see my charges.

I am a permanent resident in the US, and a Honduran citizen. Would these charges affect me coming back into the country, even if they were dismissed?

Comment: You need an immigration lawyer immediately. Do not leave the US (and expect to be able to return) without having received advice from an immigration lawyer.

Answer (score 3):

The immigration consequences here depend on a bunch of very specific details, including the exact elements of the criminal charges involved and the nature of the diversion program (you said you "pleaded guilty," which [may or may not amount to a criminal conviction](https://www.alllaw.com/articles/nolo/us-immigration/criminal-convictions-suspended-sentence-execution-pretrial-diversion.html) for immigration purposes depending on exactly how the diversion program was set up).

As Michael Hampton notes in comments, you need to speak to a immigration lawyer to answer these questions. Your permanent residency is too important to rely on advice from internet non-layers.

Comment: Too late for the OP, but I would advise a green card holder, or someone who is on the way to a green card, to consult an immigration attorney before pleading guilty to anything much more serious than a speeding ticket. Small, possibly negotiable, details in what is charged and how the case is handled may be important.